# Postgresql Copy - How to treat empty string as null while exporting data from postgresql using copy command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am exporting table using COPY command in CSV file with pipe delimiter. Few columns are null and few others are blank. In the CSV file blank string is exported as "" which I don't want.

Is there any option in COPY command to treat blank string as NULL?

For example I have five columns where 1st is blank while rest are null my output is coming as:

""||||

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your `COPY` statement?  Are you calling it with the `FORCE QUOTE` option?

Comment: Here is my COPY statement:

execute format('copy (select * from table) TO ''' || v_file_name || ''' WITH DELIMITER ''' || v_delimiter || ''' CSV HEADER NULL AS ''' || v_blank || ''' ');

Where v_file_name contain file name
v_delimiter contains |
v_blank is ''

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using a SELECT statement in the COPY, just replace the values you don't like.

```
copy (select case when col_1 = '' then null else col_1 end as col_1,
             case when col_2 = '' then null else col_2 end as col_2,
      ...)
...
```

Comment: That is my backup option. I am exporting more than 50 columns and I will have to use CASE for each column. I thought there might be some flag in COPY command itself.

Comment: `COPY` does have the `FORCE_NULL` flag, but it only works in the opposite direction (file to table). I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace an empty field value with a null representation,  there are several ways to approach this issue, the easiest one that I can think of is to use pgadmin's 'import/export data' (right-click on a table and from the context menu choose import/export data), complete the general tab, then go to the options tab and specify the string that represents a null value (ex. 'Null').
That would be the same as including the NULL option in a COPY (ex. NULL 'null_string').
I hope that would help, may the force be with you.
Kervin P.